# trying to do directory manipulation on local operating system with sinatra form input

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am looking to make a directory at a local file path using sinatra. To accomplish this I need to use a form input field to choose the name that the directory will be called.

here is what I have so far, unfortunately everything I found wasnt explicitly clear on how to pass an input value to a class method.

I am 6 hours into googling, help is appreciated.

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'shotgun'
require 'fileutils'

class Hello
  def make_folder
    FileUtils.mkdir_p "/Users/aronlilland/Documents/ruby/" + name_of_directory
  end
end

get '/' do
  erb :form
end

post '/' do
  # what do i put here to capture the name of the directory the user inputs?
end
```

form.erb

```
# what do I put here to link the input value with app.rb?

<form action="/form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name_of_directory">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML on your form, you've set `action='/form' method='post'`.
This means you need to make a `post '/form'` route.

In that route you can say

`FileUtils.mkdir_p "/Users/aronlilland/Documents/ruby/" + params[:name_of_directory]`

Since the form input had `name='name_of_directory'`, that becomes the key in the params hash.

By the way, passing value to a class method is easy, you just add a parameter to the method

```
class Example
  def self.class_method(parameter)
    puts parameter
  end
  def instance_method(parameter)
    puts parameter
  end
end
```